# Uploading generated resources to S3 in stage task?

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a custom plugin that generates some resource artifacts in a task `genWro`. My plugin also sets:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= genWro in Compile
```

that takes care of creating the resources during packaging.

I want to then take the resulting `Seq[java.util.File]` that `resourceGenerators` returns and upload them to S3 during **sbt-native-packager**'s `stage` task.

I'd actually like to only generate these resources and upload them during `stage`, and not during packaging - but one thing at a time. Basically, I only want to generate and upload the files during my production build which calls `sbt clean stage` and skip it during local development which I only need to call `sbt run`.

Comment: My understanding is that `stage` uses `resourceGenerators in Compile` and what you're asking for is by design. I might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks Jacek. I'm fine with how `resourceGenerators` is triggered. My main concern is how to get the `Seq[File]` result from the task into a custom task that uploads those files to S3, and to have that custom task called only if `stage` is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comment where you said *"My main concern is how to get the Seq[File] result from the task into a custom task that uploads those files to S3, and to have that custom task called only if stage is invoked."*, the answer could be as follows.

You've got the `stage` task that comes from the [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) plugin.

```
> help stage
Create a local directory with all the files laid out as they would be in the final distribution.
```

You've also another task, say `s3deploy`, that transfers `resourceGenerators` to S3.

```
lazy val s3deploy = taskKey[Unit]("Deploys files to S3")

s3deploy := {
  println(s"Files to transfer: ${(resourceGenerators in Compile).value}")
}
```

And here comes a solution - wire `s3deploy` to `stage`:

```
(stage in Universal) := {
    val _ = s3deploy.value
    (stage in Universal).value
}
```

The entire `build.sbt` follows:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

packageArchetype.java_application

lazy val s3deploy = taskKey[Unit]("Deploys files to S3")

s3deploy := {
  println(s"Files to transfer: ${(resourceGenerators in Compile).value}")
}

(stage in Universal) := {
    val _ = s3deploy.value
    (stage in Universal).value
}
```

Comment: (resourceGenerators in Compile).value

didn't really get me the list of files that have been generated. I had to use

    IO.listFiles

on the directory - which is no big deal, just not what I expected.